# How do you setup Egit in Eclipse when you are a contributor of a GitHub Repo

Tags: github, egit

I'm new to using a Git (VCS), but I was able to setup Egit with my GitHub repo and successfully make commits and such to the repo. A fellow friend who also is new to using Git/GitHub is having issues using that same repo in Egit when he is added as a contributor.

My question is, how does a contributor of a GitHub repo use Egit to get the latest files from GitHub and also make commit's to the project, and how do we use Egit to make sure we all have the updated files from the GitHub repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you both have contributor role, the workflow should be exactly the same on his machine. I suggest to install Mylyn and also the [Mylyn github connector](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/github-mylyn-connector#.UEH3XorN-4o), as that makes importing projects from github much easier by providing a dedicated import wizard (File, Import, git, github).

The hardest part might be the setup of the SSH keys, especially on Windows, if you want to use SSH authentication. In that case, you need specify your key files in the Eclipse preferences (General, Network, SSH).

Besides that, both of you just need to pull, commit and push to upstream afterwards. There is not exactly a real need to always be up to date, as you can merge very easily in git.